# Kubectl port forward works from command line but silently fails from Ansible task

Tags: kubernetes, ansible

I am learning to automate kubernetes cluster using Ansible

I am able to create the cluster and run `kubectl apply -f service` and `kubectl apply -f deployment` through ansible task and they work fine, but when I run `kubectl port-forward service/simple-api 3000:3000 &` in the output, it shows command executed successfully but when I check for running services on my target host, It didn't start. Although when I run the same command directly on the host terminal it works properly.

[image]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of error messages; it makes it impossible for others to search for errors that are the same as yours; the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) has more details

Answer (score 1):

You will need a [`nohup`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/eoan/en/man1/nohup.1.html) in front of that command in order for it to survive the ssh disconnect that happens at the end of the `command:` or `shell:` task